# need to connect Django project with NGINX, certbot and ngrok

Tags: django, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a Django project, made a file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/griphr-backend` which include :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 31bb-156-220-68-78.ngrok-free.app;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # Django app runs on port 8000
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

used the ngrok to get this domain `31bb-156-220-68-78.ngrok-free.app`

I run this command:

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Now when run `sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d 31bb-156-220-68-78.ngrok-free.app` get this:

> Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator:
> standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
> Domain: 31bb-156-220-68-78.ngrok-free.app   Type:   unauthorized
> Detail: 2600:1f16:d83:1202::6e:2: Invalid response from
> https://acme.ngrok.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BpCRbnqugK_D_Wys3DOw-5FOQQ8fuWQss1ZMFNuTpO4?host=31bb-156-220-68-78.ngrok-free.app:
> 404
>
> Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files
> from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80.
> Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can
> accept inbound connections from the internet.
>
> Some challenges have failed. Ask for help or search for solutions at
> https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile
> /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for
> more details.

How make certbot work to generare ssl cert?

Comment: Are you using Pro version of Ngrok (paid version) or the free version?

Comment: I use the free version

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think the issue is using the Ngrok free version. not sure.